# Meteor-Mongodb userdata publish settings

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm about to open a Meteor web app to my students, and I obviously need to keep the data in the Users collection private (each student should have access to her own 'results'). But the "admin" role needs to have more access. Here's the publish info (/server/main.js):

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function() {
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['admin'])) {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, {fields: {
            _id: 1,
            createdAt: 1,
            username: 1,
            emails: 1,
            profile: 1,
            lastAccess: 1,
            roles: 1
            }}
        )};

    if (this.userId) {
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {
             results: 1
            }
        });
    } else {
        this.ready();
    }
});
```

My question is: is this publishing setup sufficiently secure against a malicious user?

Comment: You can keep `type` key in `users` collection and check the access/permission in server side when a method is called. In client side anyone can manipulate data, but when you are sending data from server side you can perform necessary check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**.

---

Remember that you don't need to publish any collections to retrieve the data of the user that's signed-in. On the client side you can use `Meteor.user()` without a subscription.

Hence, you will only need to subscribe to `userData` if you want to display information about users other than the one signed-in.

Also, remember that when you're returning a Mongo Cursor, you don't have to call `this.ready()`.

So, your publication becomes:

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function() {
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['admin'])) {
        return Meteor.users.find({}, { fields: {
            _id: 1,
            createdAt: 1,
            username: 1,
            emails: 1,
            profile: 1,
            lastAccess: 1,
            roles: 1
        }});
    }
});
```